# Need to instantiate the child class members from parent class constructor using reflection and annotations

Tags: java

I am creating an automation framework. Here is my problem

FRAMEWORK CLASSES

```
class SomeFrameworkObject {
        public class SomeFrameworkObject(String a, int b, String c) {
            ....
        }
}
abstract class MyFrameWorkClass {
        public MyFrameWorkClass() {
            initializeMembers();
        }
        protected initializeMembers();
}
```

How client should use this

```
public class ClientClass extends MyFrameWorkClass {
    SomeFrameworkObject abc1;
    SomeFrameworkObject abc2;
    SomeFrameworkObject abc3;
    ... 
    public ClientClass() {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    protected initalizeMembers() {
        abc1 = new SomeFrameworkObject("xyz", 123, "mno");
        abc2 = new SomeFrameworkObject("ddddd", 765, "aaaaa");
        abc3 = new SomeFrameworkObject("pqrs", 987, "abcd");
    }
}
public class ClientTestClass() {
    ClientClass clientClass = new ClientClass();
    ...
}
```

Since there could be lots of ClientClasses in the client code and each class would have many instances of the SomeFrameworkObject classs, I wanted something like below to get rid of boilerplate code:

```
public class ClientClass extends MyFrameWorkClass {
    @FrameworkAnnotation("xyz", 123, "mno")
    SomeFrameworkObject abc1;
    @FrameworkAnnotation("ddddd", 765, "aaaaa")
    SomeFrameworkObject abc2;
    @FrameworkAnnotation("pqrs", 987, "abcd")
    SomeFrameworkObject abc3;
    ...

    public ClientClass() {
        super();
    }
}
```

The only thing I know is I can create the instance of SomeFrameworkObject using reflection and reading the annotation values.

But my question is how should I make sure that when client creates a new instance of ClientClass, the SomeFrameworkObjects are automatically instantiated. Is it possible to know the members of ClientClass(child) from MyFrameWorkClass(parent), and put the logic in the constructor of MyFrameWorkClass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I thought that it won't be possible to modify a child class in a parent class constructor because the initialization of the child class it not completed, but then I wasn't sure and had to try it out. So I found that it is possible and learned something today :)

To answer your question, yes it is possible, here is my test code, it will help you solving your particular problem:

Annotation:

```
@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME )
@Target( ElementType.FIELD )
public @interface Annotation {
    // empty
}
```

Child:

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    private @Annotation String test;

    public Child() {
        System.out.println( this.test );
    }

    public static void main( final String[] args ) {
        new Child();
    }

}
```

Parent:

```
public class Parent {

    private @Annotation String testOfParent;

    public Parent() {
        for ( int i = 0; i < this.getClass().getDeclaredFields().length; i++ ) {
            Field field = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()[i];
            System.out.println( field );

            for ( int j = 0; j < field.getDeclaredAnnotations().length; j++ ) {
                java.lang.annotation.Annotation annotation = field.getDeclaredAnnotations()[j];
                System.out.println( annotation );
            }

            try {
                field.setAccessible( true );
                field.set( this, "Hello World!" );
            } catch ( IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex ) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.